# Google App Script to trigger email

Tags: email, triggers, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get an email to fire alerting me if a column in a Google Sheet =X.

I've tried using the notification system using using the EQ operator to turn on when a cell equals X, this changes a cell and the notification system is supposed to send an email right away.  It's not working that way, the email never fires.

I'm think I need a script that would fire an email if a cell =X which would be nice because I could customize the email so it made more sense.  (i.e. "The conference room your event is being held has reached capacity, you should remove it from the reservation form")

I am new to Google Scripts and could use a little help creating the email trigger if cell =X script.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a script to run onEdit.

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NameOfYourSheet");
  var currentValue = sheet.getRange("A5").getValue();
  if (currentValue == (whateverValueYoureLookingFor)) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@domain.com", "ALERT: The cell in the sheet is equal to X!", "The message body that you want to send.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Phil I can't seem to get it to fire with this script, it might be something I'm doing wrong?

Here is the sheet.  I've tried various things like using another sheet to gauge the value in the first one using the EQ operator and then testing for TRUE.

[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai_2YLvaQba0dGtCbFdmeDF6bHNaY0p5NnNOemZtcXc&usp=sharing[/link]

But one problem I'm having is when I import data from one sheet to another the formula changes on the second sheet when a form entry happens?

Comment: The trigger you are looking for from this is onFormSubmit().

Comment: I put what the code should look like [here](http://pastebin.com/Bm8qX2af). When you submit a form, it adds to the last row, so retrieve the cell in (last row, column B). If it's equal to 6, then send the email.

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events --  the section on form submit events describes the arguments that will be passed into your method.

Comment: Thank you Phil.  I got both scripts to work.  I have a slight modifications to both scripts to get them to work blending know from both.  The one above I changed the "if" line to be:

if (currentValue = "TRUE")

and the script that you referenced in your link (http://pastebin.com/Bm8qX2af) worked when I removed one of the = symbols you had in the "if" line.

if (cellValue == "6")

Thank you so much for the code.  I added the one above to a script I was already using in my sheet to provide an email confirmation and now I'll know when I'll room capacity is reached.

Thanks again,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

```
function testSchemas() {
  var htmlout = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('data').evaluate().getContent();

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('All Exams Tracker');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var today = new Date()


  for (var i =3 ;i < last_row;i++) {
   var temp = values[i][4];
    var e_date = new Date(temp);
    if ((( e_date - today)/(1000*60*60*24)) < 10 && e_date > today){
      var cond = "done" }
    break; }
Logger.log(cond);  

  if (cond == "done"){


 MailAppv.sendEmail({
    to: '*************************************************************',
     subject: 'Exam Coming Next Week',
    htmlBody: htmlout,
  });

  }}
```

This will html file data (given below) when triggered.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;

}
</style>
</head>
<table style = "border: 1px solid black; border-style: collapse;">
<?   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('All Exams Tracker');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();

  var today = new Date();?>

  <tr style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">

    <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">Exam Name</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">Exam Date</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">Priority</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">College Predictor Status</th>
     <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">Rank Predictor Status</th>

</tr>

  <? for (var i =3 ;i < last_row;i++) {
   var temp = values[i][4];
    var e_date = new Date(temp);
    if ((( e_date - today)/(1000*60*60*24)) < 10 && e_date > today) {


   if (values[i][12] != ""){
  var col_status = "Live"}
  else
  if (values[i][11] != ""){
  col_status = "Uploaded and Tested"}
  else
  if (values[i][10] != ""){
  col_status = "Data Processed"}
  else
  if (values[i][9] != ""){
  col_status = "Template Ready"}

  else
  col_status = "Not initiated yet"

   if (values[i][19] != ""){
   var rank_status = "Live"}
  else
  if (values[i][18] != ""){
  rank_status = "Uploaded and Tested"}
  else
  if (values[i][17] != ""){
  rank_status = "Data Processed"}
  else
  rank_status = "Not Initiated yet"   


  ?>
<tr>

    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;"><?= values[i][2]?></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;"><?= values[i][4]?></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;"><?= values[i][8]?></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;"><?= col_status?></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;"><?= rank_status?></td>

</tr>
<? } }?>
</table>
<br><br>
<p><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fzbRCvnNfuVTCEuRnncJxb1VW7f-tkSEywntzaTugZQ/edit#gid=0">Click Here For More Details</a></p>
</html>
```