# Google Script: Email Alert with report

Tags: google-app-engine, email, triggers, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that is continually being updated. On Tuesday Afternoons, I want to receive a report via email of rows with a certain column that is blank. For example, if C1:C100 is blank, I want an email of the entire pasted row.

I saw a previous question that helped, but I still need some guidance. I am very new to writing scripts. Essentially, I want to be able to use it as a reporting tool. So a specific person does not need to open up the doc and can delegate appropriately.

Also, another script that could possibly send an email with the spreadsheet once all the rows are completed.

[Google App Script to trigger email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754086/google-app-script-to-trigger-email/14757626#14757626)

[Send Email when value changes in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371806/send-email-when-value-changes-in-google-spreadsheet)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your specifics, but here is a general skeleton:

```
function onTuesdays() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 3; // Specify the first row that data can be in.
  var column;
  var rowComplete;
  var rows = [];

  var recipients = 'something@something.com';
  var subject    = 'Tuesday Afternoon Report';
  var message    = '';

  for (var i = firstRow; i <= s.getLastRow(); i++) {
    column = 1;
    rowComplete = true;

    do {
      if (s.getRange(i, column).isBlank()) {
        rows.push(i);
        rowComplete = false;
      }
      else column++;
    }
    while (column <= s.getLastColumn() && rowComplete);
  }

  if (rows.length == 0) message += 'There were no empty cells this week.';
  else {
    message += 'The following rows had empty cells this week:<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) message += '<li>' + rows[i] + '</li>';
    message += '</ul>';
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, message);
}
```

I'm not sure how you want the information to be displayed, but that should give you a general start.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow this is great. Just gave it a try. There are a few things I've noticed, if there is no data (blank worksheet) it will state that there were no empty cells this week. As soon as data is entered, the script looks at the farthest data down and to the right and includes anything in between. 

Let's say I only want the script to concentrate on a specific range, how would I go about in adjusting the code. 

As of now, the script will state "The following rows had empty cells this week:<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>" 

Anyway, to get a copy & paste version of the actual row.

Thanks!!!

Comment: @StevenCruz I updated the code.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the Code writed before and add a Trigger Event that send you and Email automatically.

Read the section: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_triggers_programmatically